# JavaScript/HTML Form Validation

Tags: javascript, html

I am a beginner and I'm trying to write a simple form validation code.  My HTML is the following:

```
    <h1 align="center">Super Accurate Cool or Not Test</h1>

<div id="box" align="center">
    <P>Find out if you are cool or not today!!!</p>
    <form action="#" name="form1" onsubmit="return coolTest()" method="POST">
        <label>Enter your name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="inputName" name="inputName">
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

My JavaScript is this:

```
    var name = document.form1.getElementById("inputName").value;

function coolTest() {
    if (name === "Joe") {
        alert("You are so cool!");
    } else if (name === "Bob") {
        alert("You are kinda cool, but not as cool as Joe.");
    } else if (name === "") {
        alert("Please enter your name");
    } else {
        alert("You are not cool... Sorry.");
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here that is creating this to not work? Thank you! Also- here is a jsfiddle I already have: http://jsfiddle.net/tjhillard/ZQTq5/4/embedded/result/

Comment: Funniest code example I ever saw here lol

Comment: this isn't an answer, but you should use `onkeyup="coolTest();"` in the text input instead. That way they'll get an alert as soon as they type the e in Joe without having to submit.

Comment: Not the solution to your question, but *joe* and *Joe* give different results. A way to solve this is to convert the input to lowercase and test with lowercase names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change you function to the following and put it at the end of your document (before the closing body tag):

```
function coolTest() {
    var name = document.getElementById("inputName").value;
    if (name == "Joe") {
        alert("You are so cool!");
    } else if (name == "Bob") {
        alert("You are kinda cool, but not as cool as Joe.");
    } else if (name == "") {
        alert("Please enter your name");
    } else {
        alert("You are not cool... Sorry.")
    }
    return false;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ZQTq5/13/)**

Note that since IDs are unique, you want to use `document.getElementById("inputName").value;` instead of `document.form1.getElementById("inputName").value;`

Comment: good answer. to add to this, `document.forms['formName'].elements['submitButtonName'].value` would be valid.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
var name = document.form1.getElementById("inputName").value;
```

Should be inside function `coolTest()`. So, every time `coolTest()` is called, `name` will be refreshed with input value

Answer (score 0):

`getElementById` should be query with `document` not with `document.form1`

It should be

`var name = document.getElementById("inputName").value;`

instead of

```
var name = document.form1.getElementById("inputName").value;
```

And this line should be into function definition `function coolTest() {`

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8KY8J/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Input:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" onclick="coolTest()">
```

Form validate:

```
function coolTest() {
    var name = document.getElementById("inputName").value;
    var isvalid = true;
    if (name === "Joe") {
        alert("You are so cool!");
        isvalid = true; //this a valid I suppose :P
    } else if (name === "Bob") {
        alert("You are kinda cool, but not as cool as Joe.");
        isvalid = false;
    } else if (name === "") {
        alert("Please enter your name");
        isvalid = false;
    } else {
        alert("You are not cool... Sorry.");
        isvalid = false;
    }

    return isvalid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In jsfiddle while writing Javascript code you have to change default `onLoad to No wrap in <body>` which automatically adds JS at the end within body tag.

[image: Jsfidlde img]

After the above change it will work **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZQTq5/15/)**